# Python Keras Image Recognition using Tensorflow model.predict returns [[0.]]

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, keras, image-recognition

I've been following the tutorial [here](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) to process images of cats, and see if a specific picture contains a cat.  The data set I use is [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data).  Is there something missing in the way I read in an image for testing?  In my results from model.predict(filePath), I always get the value '[[0.]]' when reading an image containing a cat.  The train and validation sets seem to work correctly.  I am only having issues reading in an image. (Source code is copied from [here](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d))

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = 'data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
nb_train_samples = 2000
nb_validation_samples = 800
epochs = 50
batch_size = 16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save_weights('first_try.h5')


def _LoadImage(filePath):
    test_image = image.load_img(filePath, target_size = (150,150))
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
    return test_image


test_this = _LoadImage('test.jpg')
result = model.predict(test_this)
print(result)
```

Comment: You get the result [[0.]] for one image of a cat. Isn't that the label of a cat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like "0" is the label of cat ("The training archive contains 25,000 images of dogs and cats. Train your algorithm on these files and predict the labels for test1.zip (1 = dog, 0 = cat)."), so your model predictions seem to be correct. Remember that the model is predicting (cat and dog) labels and not what class string you might be corresponding with the labels yourself. Try feeding an image of a dog and you should get "1" in return.

Comment: So i currently have my data only trained to recognize cats.  The 'test.jpg' image is currently an image of a dog.  After I run my code, I still get [[0.]].  Let's say I only want to detect cats (I don't care about everything else, dogs, cars, etc).  Why would I be getting a [[0.]] for a picture of a dog?

Comment: "So i currently have my data only trained to recognize cats." Then that is all it is going to do. 

The classification problem you really want to tackle is telling between what is a cat and what isn't. So you would have 2 classes: "Cat" and "Not cat". Everything that isn't a cat, including dogs, in your training set would be labeled as "Not cat".